# How to create child html for checkout.cart.item.renderers

Tags: product, magento-2.1, configurable-product, cart

i am recently try to create child html form **checkout.cart.item.renderers** so i will add my custom text on each product in cart page. i have tried all  solution but not got correct solution or my bad luck.

i have try following code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="DD\DeliveryDate\Block\Index\Index" name="deliverydate_index_index" template="DD_DeliveryDate::deliverydate_index_index.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Any one have solution for this.